# Jboss wildfly server hangs on rest request

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I am currently working on one project. It's basically chat app running on jboss server. I have problem when I start a server and try to register new user. My register rest request is successfully executed ever 5-6 time, otherwise server hangs after rest request is executed and than I need to restart it. Sometimes when my register request is successfully executed and I try to log in as new user server agan hangs after login rest request is executed.

I tried to find some similar problem on internet but I couldn't. Can somebody help me. My whole project code is here
https://github.com/MiselAdemi/AgentTechnology

and here I make my login and register rest requests https://github.com/MiselAdemi/AgentTechnology/blob/master/ChatAppWeb/src/ws/WSManager.java#L122

Comment: 89 files and 1500+ lines of code - if you can't narrow things down nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: In this file here (https://github.com/MiselAdemi/AgentTechnology/blob/master/ChatAppWeb/src/ws/WSManager.java#L122) you can see `login` and `register` rest request to server. It is triggered on button click using angular (https://github.com/MiselAdemi/AgentTechnology/blob/master/ChatAppWeb/WebContent/js/controllers.js). On server side my rest endpoint for `login` and for `register` is here (https://github.com/MiselAdemi/AgentTechnology/blob/master/UserAppEJB/ejbModule/session/UserBean.java#L64)